# How to Access a value of a button?

Tags: android, button, service

I am new to android.
In my Activity class i get a link value by hitting an URL as below code.

```
  try {

                            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name = jsonobject.getString("Sno");
                                String Tktid = jsonobject.getString("TKTID");
                                link = jsonobject.getString("Link");

                                List list = new List(jsonobject.getString("Sno"), jsonobject.getString("TKTID"),jsonobject.getString("Link"));
                                tktList.add(list);

                                Log.i("website content", name);
                                Log.i("website content", Tktid);
                                Log.i("website content", link);

                            }

                            //creating custom adapter object
                            ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(tktList, getApplicationContext());


                            //adding the adapter to listview
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //displaying the error in toast if occurrs
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

And i am Assigning that value to a button in a **Adapter** class like below.

```
  TextView textViewName = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        TextView textViewImageUrl = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewImageUrl);
        Button btupdate = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btupdate);
        List hero = tktList.get(position);
        btupdate.setText(hero.getLink());
        btupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mCtx, Main3Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("Link",view.getId());
                mCtx.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Now here what my requirement is to Access that assigned link value in an other activity to retrieve some data related to that value.
Please hep me any one.

Comment: You need to pass the data itself not the `View` or it's id .. You can simply pass `hero.getLink()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this:**

```
 btupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mCtx, Main3Activity.class);

                i.putExtra("Link",btupdate.getText().toString().trim());
                    (or) 
                i.putExtra("Link",hero.getLink());
                 mCtx.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Inside **Main3Activity.java**

```
   Oncreate(){
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String message = bundle.getString("Link");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just replace this below code

```
TextView textViewName = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    TextView textViewImageUrl = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewImageUrl);
    Button btupdate = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btupdate);
    List hero = tktList.get(position);
    btupdate.setText(hero.getLink());
    btupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(mCtx, Main3Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("Link",hero.getLink());
            mCtx.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```